# Different wx created menus in different modules

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I have built multiple menus each in its own module.
The menu.py module imports the sub menu then creates an instance displaying the sub menu.

My problem is returning to the main menu (menu.py) from the sub menu.
Heres the main menu code.
menu.py

```
from gui import *
import wx
from tools import Tools
from vehicles import VehicleMainMenu
from ladders import LadderMainMenu


class TopMenu(MainMenu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        MainMenu.__init__(self, parent)

    def close_bigbutton_click(self, event):
        exit(0)

    def tools_button_click( self, event ):
        self.GetParent()  # This assigns parent frame to frame.
        self.Close()  # This then closes frame removing the main menu.
        frame = Tools(None)
        frame.Centre()
        frame.Show()

    def vehicle_button_click( self, event ):
        self.GetParent()  # This assigns parent frame to frame.
        self.Close()  # This then closes frame removing the main menu.
        frame = VehicleMainMenu(None)
        frame.Centre()
        frame.Show()

    def ladder_button_click( self, event ):
        self.GetParent()  # This assigns parent frame to frame.
        self.Close()  # This then closes frame removing the main menu.
        frame = LadderMainMenu(None)
        frame.Centre()
        frame.Show()
```

My original thought was to import the main module into each sub module and just do the following in each submenu module

vehicles.py

```
class VehicleMainMenu(VehicleMenu):
def __init__(self, parent):
    VehicleMenu.__init__(self, parent)


    def veiw_vehicle_click(self, event):
        self.GetParent()  # This assigns parent frame to frame.
        self.Close()  # This then closes frame removing the main menu.
        frame = VehicleListGrid(None)
        frame.Centre()
        frame.Show(

    #This was the code to return to the main menu (main.py)
    def back_click( self, event ):
        self.GetParent()  # This assigns parent frame to frame.
        self.Close()  # This then closes frame removing the main menu.
        frame = TopMenu(None)
        frame.Centre()
        frame.Show()
```

I am unable to import menu (menu.py) into the other submenu modules as this throws an error.  I've tried all sorts of permitations but I am unable to return the the main menu.

Help please?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by importing into sub menu model the menu.py module

```
import menu
```

then using

```
def back_click( self, event ):
    self.GetParent()  # This assigns parent frame to frame.
    self.Close()  # This then closes frame removing the main menu.
    frame = menu.TopMenu(None) #never used menu. in previous attempts
    frame.Centre()
    frame.Show()
```

to get back the main menu (TopMenu) in the menu.py module.